# Adding a NSMutableArray which is Parsed XML value to a AppDelegate good or bad?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Is adding a `NSMutableArray` which is Parsed XML value to a `AppDelegate` good or bad practice?

Im trying to find the best solution for a fairly large XML that gets parsed and then added to a `NSMutableArray`.

Comment: It depend on your requirement. If you want that array on all UIViewController that you can do this otherwise not.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good practice to save data in `AppDelegate`. AppDelegate should be used for initialization and for receiving application level events as a mediator between OS and Application.

You can create a singleton `DataManager` which will keep all the data fetched in a session. Make `Composite Model objects` for your structures and keep them as collections in DataManager. If you can provide more information about the type of data you are trying to persist, we can provide suggestions.

More read on [Singleton Objects](http://www.johnwordsworth.com/2010/04/iphone-code-snippet-the-singleton-pattern/)